# DJI Mavic Pro Navigation System Error, After Crash

Tags: troubleshooting, dji, repairs, dji-mavic-pro-1

After repairing my hardly crashed Mavic Pro, I encountered this error: "Navigation system error, check redundancy state", and here's what I did to clear out this error:

- IMU calibration
- Compass calibration
- Vision sensors calibration
- GPS board replacement
- Firmware refresh V.01.04.0500

But none of these worked! And I'm just hoping I can find some other solution before going through IMU replacement.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was actually from the IMU not sending out commands! Had to replace the whole ESC board, and it worked, finally!!!